# how to order in Sequelize for MySQL if i want to show certain condition in priority?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

in my project,i need to show data with attribute 'status == 2' in priority,then order by date,here's the model:

```
var Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    id:{type: sequelize.INTEGER()},
    status:{type: sequelize.INTEGER()},
    date:{type: sequelize.DATE}
});
```

status start from 0 to 5, and current ordering:

```
Model.findAll({
    order: [
        ['date','DESC']
    ]
});
```

example,there are three data:

```
data1:{id:1,status:2,date:2016-08-16},
data2:{id:2,status:3,date:2016-08-17},
data3:{id:3,status:2,date:2016-08-18},
data4:{id:4,status:1,date:2016-08-16}
```

and the expected output after order would be like:

```
data3:{id:3,status:2,date:2016-08-18},
data1:{id:1,status:2,date:2016-08-16},
data2:{id:2,status:3,date:2016-08-17},
data4:{id:4,status:1,date:2016-08-16}
```

What should i do? Please help me.

Comment: Could you add an example of your expected output? Maybe this helps to grasp what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Fuzzzzel thank you! I just add an example,please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This will get all values with status equal to 2, then it will order them by date.

```
Model.findAll({
   order: [
      ['status':'ASC'],
      ['date':'DESC']
   ]
 })
```

Comment: sorry i didn't make my question clear,i expected to get data with all kind of status but show "status == 2" in priority, I've updated an example in the question,please check it out,thank you!

Comment: That's can solve the problem! Thanks! But I still wonder what if I got other data that status smaller than 2,how can i put these data behind?

Comment: Then you aren't sorting. The sample output you updated (again) is not possible with sorting or any single query. It looks random, since it's not sorted by status, or by date.